# Отправка данных из WYSIWYG

Tags: wysiwyg, php, javascript

Есть JS-WYSIWYG редактор.
Вот я не пойму, как HTML код из этого редактора добавить в БД mySQL, например, или занести в переменную РНР?

```
 <script>// *********************** //
 ШАГ 1: Выводим iframe и получаем
 доступ к нему //
 ***********************

 // Выводим в HTML-поток iframe
 document.write("<iframe scrolling='no'
 frameborder='no' src='#' id='frameId'
 name='frameId'></iframe><br/>"); //
 Определим Gecko-браузеры, т.к. они
 отличаются в своей работе от Оперы и
 IE var isGecko =
 navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("gecko")
 != -1; // Получаем доступ к объектам
 window & document для ифрейма var
 iframe = (isGecko) ?
 document.getElementById("frameId") :
 frames["frameId"]; var iWin =
 (isGecko) ? iframe.contentWindow :
 iframe.window; var iDoc = (isGecko) ?
 iframe.contentDocument :
 iframe.document;

 // *********************** // ШАГ 2:
 Добавим на пустую страницу ифрейма
 произвольный HTML-код //
 ***********************

 // Формируем HTML-код iHTML =
 "<html><head>\n"; iHTML +=
 "<style>\n"; iHTML += "body, div, p,
 td {font-size:12px;
 font-family:tahoma; margin:0px;
 padding:0px;}"; iHTML += "body
 {margin:5px;}"; iHTML += "</style>\n";
 iHTML += "<body><u>Содержимое</u> с
 <b>HTML</b>-<i>разметкой</i></body>";
 iHTML += "</html>"; // Добавляем его с
 помощью методов объекта document
 iDoc.open(); iDoc.write(iHTML);
 iDoc.close();

 // *********************** // ШАГ 3:
 Инициализация свойства designMode
 объекта document //
 ***********************

 if (!iDoc.designMode)
 alert("Визуальный режим редактирования
 не поддерживается Вашим браузером");
 else iDoc.designMode = (isGecko) ?
 "on" : "On";

 // *********************** // ШАГ 4:
 Простейшие элементы редактирования:
 жирность, курсив, подчеркивание //
 ***********************

 // Выведем HTML-код этих элементов
 document.write("<input type='button'
 value='Ж' onclick='setBold()'
 class='bold' />");
 document.write("<input type='button'
 value='К' onclick='setItal()'
 class='ital' />");
 document.write("<input type='button'
 value='Ч' onclick='setUnder()'
 class='under' />"); // Запишем код
 функции, для выставления
 форматирования // Используется метод
 execCommand объекта document function
 setBold() {  iWin.focus(); 
 iWin.document.execCommand("bold",
 null, ""); } function setItal() { 
 iWin.focus(); 
 iWin.document.execCommand("italic",
 null, ""); } function setUnder() { 
 iWin.focus(); 
 iWin.document.execCommand("underline",
 null, ""); } </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что-то сильно как-то берешь проблему.
Ведь есть описание как подключить редактор на страницу.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Installation почитай тут.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался :)

Comment: Не за что. ;)